# trimming a string within a div

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div class="name" >
product name
</div>
```

When I calculate the length of the string of `product name` using the following code:

```
var productnames = document.getElementsByClassName('name');
productnames[0].innerHTML.trim();
console.log(productnames);
console.log(productnames[0].innerHTML.length);
```

My trim prototype function is

```
String.prototype.trim = function() {
       return this.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
};
```

The result is `64`. However, if I run the same code on:

```
<div class="name" >product name</div>
```

The result is `13`.

Is there a way to remove the spaces before and after of the `innerHTML` string so that I am left with just product name without removing backspaces? a jQuery solution is fine also.

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/

Comment: Do `console.log(productnames[0].innerHTML.trim().length)`. The `trim` function **returns** a new string. Just calling `productnames[0].innerHTML.trim();` without doing anything with the return value doesn't have any effect.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using jQuery plugin. Its simpler than that.

```
$.trim(stringHere);
```

So your code would be

```
$.trim($('.name').text());
```

In the code, the `$('.name').text()` would be the string provided to the method which has to be trimmed down. I have created an example fiddle for you to check how it works.

http://jsfiddle.net/afzaal_ahmad_zeeshan/dJ9SA/

For more: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/

Comment: this produced the same answer, which is `64`. I think this is because a carriage return? Here is what the string looks like: `outerHTML: "<div class="name">↵                         Barrel Basket↵                        </div>"`

Comment: jQuery would only remove white spaces. not any other character from string. It wont remove the carriage return character.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're already there:

```
var productnames = document.getElementsByClassName('name'),
    html = productnames[0].innerHTML.trim(), // returns the trimmed string
    len = html.length; // gets the length of the string

console.log(html); // "product name"
console.log(len);` // 12
```